# Is listening to sound of porn allowed. Or other tyoes of porn

Tags: pornography

Assalamu alaikum
I wanted to ask is that is listening to the sound of porn allowed. Like i dont watch the video but just hear it to ease sexual tension. And i heard that porn is zinah of eyes. But what if i watch a video that contains no penetration or private parts but like a man kissing the woman feet or something, are these videos allowed in islam.
Thank you if you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pornography is Haram in Islam and you must guard your eyes from from those things which Allah has forbidden. You said you didn't watch them but hear them. But there is a huge possibility that temptation will force you watch those which Allah has forbidden. I recommend you not to watch these type of movie because if they contain nudity it is Haram. Brother please stay away from these and watch movies that have no Haram content because your Nafs(desire) might force you to sin and there will be satanic whispers. Jazakallah Khairan